# Partial updates with PopulateWithNonDefaultValues overwrites null fields in sub classes

Tags: servicestack

I have a class "company" that contains a sub class "address". "Address" contains a field "city" and a field "postalcode". Both nullable (strings).

I have an existing company with both fields in the address class populated. What I am trying to do, is to update the postalcode field using a company object with only one of the fields in the address class populated.

The result is not what I wanted. The "city" field in the destination object is overwritten along with the "postalcode".

Seems to me it replaces the address field instead of only the fields populated in the class.

Anyone know to to solve this?

Original object:

```
 "name": "Some company",
 "address": {
        "city": "New York",
        "postalCode": "1234"
    }
```

Updated using:

```
 "name": null,
 "address": {
        "city": null,
        "postalCode": "1122"
    }
```

Ends up in:

```
 "name": "Some company",
 "address": {
        "city": null,
        "postalCode": "1122"
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Auto Mapping](http://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping) `PopulateWithNonDefaultValues()` extension method will **replace** the Address property if it's not null, which is why the resulting Address ends up using the updated Address, i.e. it **doesn't merge** both Addresses, it replaces it with the updated non-null address.

If you wanted to merge the Addresses, you'd need to do that separately, e.g:

```
original.Address.PopulateWithNonDefaultValues(updated.Address);
updated.Address = null; // skip populating Address
original.PopulateWithNonDefaultValues(updated);
```

Comment: Yes that was what I thought. In complex structures you would have to traverse down the object structure and handle all the sub classes.
Looks like I have to rely on the consumers of my API to populate all values in the request class.